# Error when print char array without index cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio

I'm new with C++ and I'v write this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main() {
    char s[2] = { 'a', 'l' };
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

And when I run this code I get wrong output like this:

```
al╠╠╠╠╠╠H²O
```

Why? because when I learn C++ I'v read when I print characters array I will see array elements like string.

Comment: `s` isn't zero-terminated. When passed to `cout` it decays into a `char*`, a C-style string. It needs to be zero-terminated, since there is no length information attached.

Comment: ╠ is 0xCC in codepage 437, and [MSVC fills 0xCC to uninitialized memory to help debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714). That means you've accessed uninitialized memory. You can find tons of questions about ╠ and 0xCC here on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your char array is not zero terminated, std::cout does not know where your string ends.

You need to do this:

```
char s[3] = { 'a', 'l', '\0'};
```